# find subdirectories with lowest number

Tags: find

I am trying to list all subdirectories with the lowest number.

For example, for the following list:

```
/100/2001  
/100/2003  
/101/2001  
/101/2004  
/102/2000  
/102/2003  
/102/2005
```

I am looking to obtain only:

```
/100/2001  
/101/2001  
/102/2000
```

Comment: Do you provide this input for the wanted solution or shall the solution generate it itself? If the latter: Are there always two levels? Are all entries guaranteed to be numbers?

Comment: On that particular input, GNU `uniq -w4` would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the lowest directory from each directory, you will need to sort the output in each directory.

/100/2001
/100/2003
/101/2001
/101/2004
/102/2000
/102/2003
/102/2005

the ls command automatically does that, but it does alpha-numeric sorting by default.  If all your sub-subdirectories have names with the same length then that will be acceptable.

`SUBDIRLIST=10?
for SUBDIR in $SUBDIRLIST
do
   ls -d $SUBDIR/???? | head -1
done`

How this works:
`for SUBDIR in $SUBDIRLIST`
  Look in each directory in the list.  The list is defined in the previous line.  I chose to use 10? to select entries that are three characters long and start with 10 but you could just as well have said `SUBDIR=*` if you want to use everything.

`ls -d $SUBDIR/????`

- `ls` command to display sorted entries of the contents of $SUBDIR
- The `????` selects only entries that are four characters long. You may want to choose * if you don't care, or if you have other directories that should be ignored, limit it further using an expression like `20??`

`| head -1`
- Pass the list through the "head command"
- Head will display only the first line and discard the rest.

You need a slightly different solution if all the directory names are not the same length, eg:
`SUBDIRLIST=10?
for SUBDIR in $SUBDIRLIST
do
   find $SUBDIR -depth 1 | sort -n | head -1
done`

In this case we use find because ls would sort the entries, but it would do it wrong, so it is redundant.  Find doesn't sort the entries (be default).

`sort -n` then sorts the found items, where `-n` makes sure they are treated as numbers, so that 20 comes before 100.

Once again `head -1` discards everything except the first line.

And finally the `SUBDIRLIST=10?` statement selects only subdirectories starting with 10 and having three characters in the name.  You can limit it more or less, depending on your needs.  For example `SUBDIRLIST=*` selects everything, `SUBDIRLIST=???` selects all entries having three characters.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
ls -1d /*/200{0,1}
```

Ouput:

```
/100/2001
/101/2001
/102/2000
```

Comment: way to specific...

Answer (score 0):

For this input this can be done with:

```
awk -F/ 'min[$2]==0 { min[$2]=$3; next; }; 
 { if (min[$2]>$3) min[$1]=$3;}; 
 END {for (val in min) { print "/" val "/" min[val] };}'
```

`awk` sorts by the first field. I don't know whether this is guaranteed or just coincidence. To be sure you may pipe the awk output into

```
sort --field-separator=/ -n
```

Comment: The order is unspecified. That varies from one implementation to the next. Using `--field-separator` (-t portably) without `-k` has no effect. Use `sort -nt/ -k1,1 -k2,2`

Comment: (more `-k2,2 -k3,3` as the first field is the empty one at the start)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas That was my problem with `awk`, too...

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
perl -le 'for (</*/*>){ 
              ($first,$second)=(split m{/})[1,2]; 
              push @{$entries{$first}},$second 
          }
          END{
              for (sort {$a<=>$b} keys %entries){
                  $lowest = shift sort {$a<=>$b} @{$entries{$_}};
                  print "/$_/$lowest\n";
              }
          }'
```

This assumes all your directories will have purely numerical names.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
for firstdir in `ls .`; do
  seconddir=`ls -1 ./$firstdir | head -n 1`
  echo $firstdir/$seconddir
done
```

note: this script will fail when the second directory have different digits number